# Cross Compiling for x64 on ARM (Apple Silicon)

Tags: c, macos, ld, apple-m1, stockfish

It is definitely possible to target Intel when compiling on an Apple Silicon (ARM64) system, as Xcode does that all the time when building universal bundles of an app. However, I am unable to replicate this compiling a C program with `make` (specifically Stockfish).

##### What I've tried

I'm invoking `make` like so: `make build ARCH=x86-64-modern COMP=clang` (the same command works when I substitute `x86-64-modern` for `apple-silicon`). I've tried using the `gcc` compiler, which also worked when targeting the `apple-silicon` arch.

##### The problem

The `make build` command terminates with a bunch of errors, most importantly:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Above the error is a bunch of lines complaining that a file was built for an "unknown bitcode architecture:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file <name>.o, lto file was built for unknown bitcode architecture which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): <name>.o
```

So, it seems like the compilation phase succeeds, but the linking phase fails due to missing symbols. How would I acquire and provide the missing symbols to `ld` such that it can link successfully?